# ASP.Net FileUpload won't accept files over the size of 10 MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Edit: Added FileUpload below.
Edit 2: So, I found a solution, but its stupid. I tried messing around with an extra FileUpload, and it accepted the bigger files just fine. Even on the same page, even following right after the first one. Deleting the first one and leaving the new didn't help, however, so my solution is a stupid workaround - having two and hiding the first one.

```
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="u-active-custom-color-2 u-border-2 u-border-white u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-custom-color-3 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-hover-custom-color-1 u-radius-30">
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPpt" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUploadPpt"
                                ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Pp][Pp][Tt][Xx])|.+\.([Pp][Pp][Tt]))"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelPptFile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </div>
```

I'm aware it's not a good option, but nothing else seems to take. Even just using the visable property on the fileUpload caused it to break, hence the two div-blocks. I'm leaving this in case someone else runs into the same issue...

Original question:
I've struggled for a few hours now and I'm at my wits end.

I have an asp:FileUpload controller, which allows users to upload files. I want to allow a bit larger files, so I've tried setting the limit to 50 MB, as shown in the except of the config file below. However, when I try selecting a file over the size of 10 MB, the control won't grab the file. Anything under 10 MB is fine and the name gets displayed, but above that is just says no file is selected. I've checked my control and it has no limits. The code behind is c#, but at this point it isn't being fired yet, so it shouldn't be too relevant.

Any tips or pieces of advice is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- Traditional API: Register a custom SessionIDManager for BotDetect requests -->
        <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" debug="false" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="51200" requestLengthDiskThreshold="51200" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.3 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /><!--50MB-->
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

```
<div class="u-active-custom-color-4 u-align-center-sm u-align-center-xs u-border-2 u-border-custom-color-4 u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-custom-color-6 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-hover-custom-color-5 u-radius-30">
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPpt" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUploadPpt"
                                ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Pp][Pp][Tt][Xx])|.+\.([Pp][Pp][Tt]))"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelPptFile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </div>
```

Once the customer clicks a "Create" button at the end of the page, the server-side script is run, which does the actual uploading. But we don't even get that far...

Comment: @PoulBak this is classic asp.net

Comment: May be somehow you are using a client-side file-size check. The web.config seems ok.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh, It doesn't seem like it's the case. I'll update the issue with my FileUpload.

Comment: Does this problem only occur on iis? can you upload a 10 MB file locally? you can also try clearing your browser's cache and try again.

Comment: @samwu, I've tried to do it in localhost as well, but with the same result. I think I tried clearing my browser, but I'll try again.

Comment: Clearing the cache did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution, but its stupid. I tried messing around with an extra FileUpload, and it accepted the bigger files just fine. Even on the same page, even following right after the first one. Deleting the first one and leaving the new didn't help, however, so my solution is a stupid workaround - having two and hiding the first one.

```
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-active-custom-color-2 u-border-2 u-border-white u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-custom-color-3 u-custom-font u-heading-font u-hover-custom-color-1 u-radius-30">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPpt" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUploadPpt"
                            ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Pp][Pp][Tt][Xx])|.+\.([Pp][Pp][Tt]))"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelPptFile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
```

I'm aware it's not a good option, but nothing else seems to take. Even just using the visable property on the fileUpload caused it to break, hence the two div-blocks. I'm leaving this in case someone else runs into the same issue...